# E-mail invitation não chega - GitLab

Tags: gitlab

Preciso adicionar outro desenvolver no repositório no **gitlab** porém convido-o e *nenhum e-mail invitation* chega no e-mail dele.

Existe alguma maneira de **adicionar** um *membro* sem ser por e-mail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem várias formas para visualizar, editar, adicionar e remover membros de um projeto, para fazer alterações precisa aceder a **Configurações> Membros do projeto**:

> Adicionar utilizador:

Mesmo ao lado de **Pessoas**, comece a digitar o nome ou o nome de usuário que deseja adicionar.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Importar usuários de outro projeto:

Você pode importar os usuários de outro projeto em seu próprio projeto, clicando no botão **Importar** membros no canto superior direito do menu **Membros**.

No menu suspenso, você pode ver apenas os projetos em que você é Master.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Convide pessoas usando seu endereço de e-mail:

Se um usuário ao qual você deseja dar acesso não possui uma conta na sua instância do *GitLab*, pode convidá-los apenas digitando seu endereço de e-mail no campo de pesquisa do usuário.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Para mais informações veja o link de ajuda do [GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/members/index.html).